# Implementing the stochastic gradient descent algorithm of the softmax regression with only NumPy

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, numpy, machine-learning

I am implementing the stochastic gradient descent algorithm. I think there is plenty of room for improvement.

```
def array2onehot(X_shape, array, start=1):
    """
    transfer a column to a matrix with each row being a onehot
    note that the array index defaults to start with 1 rather than 0
    """
    array += 1 - start if start != 1 else 0
    onehot = np.zeros(X_shape)
    onehot[np.arange(X_shape[0]), array-1] = 1
    return onehot

def stochastic_gradient_descent(self, batch, Y):
    """
    the batch contains both the X's and targets
    Y is the output produced by the forward process using the X's in the batch
    """
    ones = np.ones(batch.shape[0])
    # add the bias to the X's
    X = np.column_stack(ones, batch[:, :-1])
    T = array2onehot(X.shape, batch[:, -1])
    m = self._batch_size
    # batch size is the size of the mini batch

    count = np.zeros(self._class_size)
    # class size is the amount of classes to predict
    delta = np.zeros(self._coefficients.shape)
    for i in range(m):
        k = batch[i, -1] - 1
        count[k] += 1
        delta[:, k] += X[i] * sum(np.multiply(T[i], Y[i]))
    tmp = self._coefficients
    for i in count:
        if i == 0:
            tmp[:, i] = 0
    delta = np.nan_to_num(delta / count) - 2 * self._penalty_rate * tmp
    self._coefficients -= delta
```

Comment: It would help if you could supply some sample input and the expected output.

Comment: I'm preparing the data, which is toilsome for my task.

Comment: Well, so is reviewing. Besides, it does not need to be real data, just realistic enough (sizes, shapes).

Comment: This code doesn't run since we don't have the `self` variables aren't defined. It's also hard to know what your `start` variable is used for.

Comment: Please show the rest of the class. We're lacking context for a meaningful review now.

Comment: @Mast You are right. I will update soon if time permits. I am not familiar with the code now.

Comment: That's ok, we all got to learn at the start. Feel free to read our [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) for additional information.